# Tag [uibackgroundcolor] shouldn't exist under this name

Tags: discussion, retag-request

While the prefix `UI` often refers to Apple's `UIKit` in Stack Overflow tags, there seems to be a fundamental issue with the tag [uibackgroundcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uibackgroundcolor) because such a name doesn't exist at all in Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=uibackgroundcolor. So [its tag excerpt is currently **wrong**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/uibackgroundcolor/info).

Reading the questions using this tag, they actually often refer to UIView's [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622591-backgroundcolor) property, which is an optional UIColor.

So I believe that [uibackgroundcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uibackgroundcolor) should be renamed or removed:

- could be renamed to **[backgroundcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backgroundcolor)**
- could be renamed to **[uikit-backgroundcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit-backgroundcolor)**
- could be renamed to **[uiview-backgroundcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiview-backgroundcolor)**
- could be burninated